# In servlets, is it correct to check the magic number of uploaded files

Tags: servlets

I am tasked with handling uploaded files in a portal environment.  To this end, the user should be authenticated at the point of uploading files.  Although the uploads should only be of a certain type (JPG, PDF and PNG), I am aware that the checking of the file types at the client site can be easily spoofed.  Do others in a similar environment check the magic numbers of the uploaded files at the server side before storing uploaded files or, as the user is authenticated, simply store the file?

From perusing the web, I can see how to check the file type, however, I have been unable to ascertain whether or not this is common practice in a portal based environment.

Many thanks!

Comment: Never trust user input.

Comment: Good point!  Can you please indicate if any other portal admins out there use the magic number approach to checking the type of file at server side or is there a better / more widely accepted approach?